# Magento display discount code box only if store has codes available

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get my cart to display the discount code box only if there are valid discount codes available for that specific website/store (of which I have two).

This is what I've got so far (contained within my own copy of `coupon.phtml`)

```
<?php
/** @var $coupon Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon */
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
$validCoupons = $coupon->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('expiration_date', array('gt' => NOW()))
    ->count();
?>

<?php if($validCoupons > 0): ?>
    <!-- discount code form here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine if you're happy with checking for discount codes across all websites/stores, but I want to update it so it takes only the current website/store into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to check if there are discount rules that use coupons. Since a discount rule can have a specified coupon instead of a list of coupons. For this use the following code:

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$todayEndOfDayDate =  Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
    ->setTime('23:59:59')
    ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
    ->setTime('00:00:00')
    ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$validCouponRules = $coupon->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('coupon_type', 2)//rules that have coupons fixed or generated
    ->addFieldToFilter('website_ids', array('finset'=>Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())) //filter rules available for current website 
    ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayEndOfDayDate), // filter rules that end later than today
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null'))) //or rules that don't have an end date
    ), 'left')
    ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayStartOfDayDate), //filter rules that started today or earlier
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null'))) // or rules that don't have a start date
    ), 'left');
$validCoupons = $validCouponRules->count();
```